# variables gets undefined in my second method

Tags: angularjs, controller, execution

I'm having a controller in my angularjs application in which I call two service methods.

When the controller gets initiated my second method uses $scope values that are set in my first method. The $scope values gets undefined since I can't clearly figure out the execution order here.

Why does my second method get called before my $scope values are set in the first method? And how can I fix this in a proper way?

```
angular.module("Modal")
.controller("MyController",
    function($scope, $log, ModalService, AuthService) {

        //First method - Calls a WEB API
        AuthService.FirstMethod(function (username) {
            $scope.username = "myName"; //Is set after SecondMethod is called
            $scope.items = "MyItems";
        });

        //Second method
        //$scope values here are undefined when initiating the controller
        ModalService.SecondMethod($scope.items, $scope.username, function (selectedItem) {
            var test = selectedItem;
        });


    }
);
```

Comment: use angular $q promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
function wrapUpFirst() {
    return $q(function(resolve,reject) {
        // Execute this function
        AuthService.FirstMethod(function(result) {
            resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
            // Handle error
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

So this returns a promise which we can use below and pass the result to the second method:

```
wrapUpFirst().then(function(success) {
    // Use result for the second
    ModalService.SecondMethod(success, otherParams, func(){});
});
```